# Subplots Using Plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to create a plot using the subplot function in Plotly. I am following the examples as described [here](https://plotly.com/r/subplots/#scaled-subplots). The code I have written so far:

```
test_plot <- plot_ly(testData, x = ~timestamp, y = ~reading, 
                     color = ~vessel, colors = "Dark2",
                     yaxis = ~paste0("y", id))
test_plot <- test_plot %>% add_lines()
test_plot <- test_plot %>% subplot(nrows = 6, shareX = TRUE)
```

But I get the following error:

[image: Error Traceback]

Here's my data:

```
testData <- structure(list(timestamp = c("2019-01-02 09:00:00", "2019-01-02 09:00:00", 
"2019-01-02 09:00:00", "2019-01-03 09:00:00", "2019-01-02 09:00:00", 
"2019-01-02 09:00:00", "2019-01-03 09:00:00", "2019-01-02 09:00:00"
), vessel = c("vessel_dif_1", "vessel_dif_2", "post_vessel_1", "post_vessel_1", 
"post_vessel_2", "pre_vessel_1", "pre_vessel_1", "pre_vessel_2"), reading = c(-4L, 
2L, 58L, 60L, 50L, 54L, 56L, 52L), id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I'm completely lost on why I'm getting this error. I can copy and paste the example from the Plotly website and it works fine, but for some reason when I use my data it fails.

Additionally, I've tried turning the timestamp into a Date class using `as.Date()` and turning the tibble into a data.frame so it matches what is described in the example but that doesn't seem to be what's causing the issue. Also when I skip the subplot line, it creates a single plot with multiple lines on it.

Comment: What is the object `activated_carbons_plot` in your code? Should it be `test_plot`?

Comment: Ooops, you are correct. It should be test_plot. Corrections made, but that was not the issue

Answer (score 0):

Simply sort your data by id before plotting. This should probably not result in an error (so perhaps you should raise an issue on [github](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly)) but ... Try this:

```
testData <- read.table(text = "timestamp    vessel    reading  id  
 '2019-01-02 09:00:00'  pre_ac_1   54       5
 '2019-01-02 09:00:00'  post_ac_1  58       3
 '2019-01-02 09:00:00'  ac_dif_1   -4       1
 '2019-01-02 09:00:00'  pre_ac_2   52       6
 '2019-01-02 09:00:00'  post_ac_2  50       4
 '2019-01-02 09:00:00'  ac_dif_2   2        2
 '2019-01-03 09:00:00'  pre_ac_1   56       5
 '2019-01-03 09:00:00'  post_ac_1  60       3", header = TRUE)

# Sort by id
testData <- dplyr::arrange(testData, id)

library(plotly)

test_plot <- plot_ly(testData, x = ~timestamp, y = ~reading,
                     color = ~vessel, colors = "Dark2",
                     yaxis = ~paste0("y", id))
test_plot <- test_plot %>% 
  add_lines %>%
  add_markers()

test_plot <- test_plot %>% 
  subplot(nrows = 6, shareX = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error. It works when I paste your code directly in, but something about the structure of my data must be different. I just can't seem to figure out what. Thank you though!